# Resource Usage and Graph not aligned

Tags: microsoft-project

I have a problem trying to understand and fix a discrepancy between my Resource Graph and the Resource Usage.

There are a few days where I see the Resource Graph indicating red bars above the 100% utilization mark such as 125%, and 225%.  However, those same days for the same resource in the Resource Usage grid I can see the total hours *less* than 8 for the day.  There is no red man mark next to any of my tasks in the Gantt chart either.

I have been unsuccessful trying to identify and task that would make the resource over allocated as the Graph suggest.

I am using MS Project Professional 2010 64bit version 14.0.6112.5000

Thank you for reading this post and helping in any way.

Answer (score 0):

This had to do with two tasks overlapping at the same time during the day.  This made the graph show over allocated even though the total hours of the day were less than 8.